# ASP.Net applications splitted in different tier

Tags: asp.net, security, architecture, n-tier-architecture

I'm dealing with an architecture approach that doesn't convince me deeply, but I can't figure out a good alternative.
Basically our company is pretty much always under attack... I mean there's constant attempt of phishing, spoofing, bruteforcing, etc. attacks to our public web site.
Decision has been taken to delpoy the web apps on a 3 tier configuration (I really mean tier, not layer as often they're confused), letting the presentation tier being on a machine, in a subnet exposed to the internet, and the rest of the application being on an internal subnet, with an application server that basically expose everything needed by the presentation server or other internal system, and obvioulsy a database server.

Now, the separation between presentation and business logic, is very heavy both in terms of development and in terms of performance: use a DLL dedicated to perform data access is obviuosly faster than call a remote service to perform the same operation.

This, on the other, has been seen as the most pratical way to improve security: in this deployment model the presentation layer could be break throug by some hacker, but still, from there, they gain no access to the database, and that's the important part.

The communication between the presentation tier and the business tier is made through WCF services, exposing authenticated SOAP methods.

Moreover the approach is to let all the business logic in the BL tier, letting the presentation tier be quite "stupid": so the BL tier is not merely a secured DAL layer, but contains all the logic.

Is that an acceptable approach? There's some smarter way to handle such scenario out there, that we're missing? Would you prefer to keep BL on the presentiation tier, living just the DAL in the middle tier? And for what reason?
I'm feeling pretty unsure about our solution, so I'm asking for any advice.

Comment: Before, hackers could only attack via the presentation tier, but now they can attack the UI *and* the application server that reaches into your subnet. Haven't you just doubled the exposed area?

Comment: the presentation tier is exposed on the web, via an unsecure http protocol, but it's in a DMZ, so it has very limited connection possibility against the internal subnet, in which the DB and the BL reside. Presentation can only use authenticated soap protocol to connect the internal subnet. This should add some complexity for an hacker: they should break into the presentation server first, and then the BL tier... it's not impossible, but it's supposed to be harder.

Comment: That sounds pretty neat then - and beyond my security knowledge! Hopefully somebody more experienced will post. Good luck with it

Comment: You can find both source code and explanation ASP.Net applications splitted in different tier http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/paulabraham/Building3TierAppPA11282005053625AM/Building3TierAppPA.aspx